# Package dependency ignored by Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, dependencies, nuget

**Context**

There are two .NET Core 3.1  projects a Visual Studio 2019 16.7.2 solution.
The class lib project has a package dependency on NuGet package AutoMapper 9.0.0
The web application project has a project dependency on the class lib.

Runtime I got the "Could not load assembly AutoMapper 9.0.0.0". My first thought was some version mismatch but all projects set to .NET Core 3.1.

I've investigated, and i**n the web application project /bin folder there is no AutoMapper assembly**.
So I've investigated further, and it seems the web app project somehow ignores this implicit dependency, see picture.

**What I've tried so far:**

- I've  tried to clean all, then rebuild.
- I've  tried to exit, then restart Visual Studio

**Question**

What am I missing here?

[image]

For Kirk's comment:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\Benedetto.Abstractions\Benedetto.Abstractions.csproj" />
  <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="9.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="IdentityModel.AspNetCore.OAuth2Introspection" Version="4.0.1" />
```

Comment: Can you show the `PackageReference` element in the csproj for `Benedetto.Web.Identity`? My guess is it might be using `PrivateAssets`.

Comment: Many thx for thinking about this. Unfortunately this is not the case. I am adding the part of the .csproj file to the original question.

Comment: I've completely wiped out everything, including clearing nuget caches, deleting all /bin and /obj folders, then **restoring packages via nuget commandline for the whole solution**, then restarting VS, then rebuild, and now it works. No source or csproj files were changed. Puzzler... anyway it works now. Spent an hour with it, and yesterday it was a blocker for a half day

Comment: @g.pickardou, be glad to know that you have solved the issue by yourself. To help other community members search and handle similar issues, I have added an answer here. You can check it. Anyway, have a nice day！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, Glad to know that you have solved the issue. To add an answer here for other community members handle similar issues.

Solution

1. [clean all nuget caches first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or just delete all nuget caches under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\.nuget\packages`
2. close VS Instance, delete `bin` and `obj` folder
3. use `nuget xxx\xxx.sln` command line to restore nuget packages
4. then restart project to fix the issue.